# Do specific values of partial derivatives allow us to use the chain rule for functions of 2+ variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Given a function $f(x, y)$ and knowing that both x and y are functions of $s$ and $t$, can we use the chain rule to find, for example, the partial derivative of f with respect to s ($\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$).

To be more specific, the example could be:
$$f(1,3) = 8;$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 3;$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -1;$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} = 7;$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = 5;$$

And let's say that I have to find the partial of f with respect to s.
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \, ?$$

My reasoning is that this, in itself, is not enough. I think we need to be presented with the function itself so that we can look into its properties. I am mainly thinking about differentiability here. I seem to recal that the chain rule cannot be used if the function itself is not differentiable.

All help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\partial f / \partial s = \partial f/\partial x \cdot \partial x /\partial s + \partial f/\partial y \cdot \partial y /\partial s$

Comment: You need the points where those partial derivatives are given to match. The chain rule can be applied with numerical values like here, if we are given that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=3,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=-1,$$ 
$x(s_0,t_0)=x_0$, $y(s_0,t_0)=y_0$, and also
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s_0,t_0)=7\qquad\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s_0,t_0)=5.$$ Then you can use the chain rule to calculate 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(s_0,t_0)=3\cdot7+(-1)\cdot5.$$

Comment: And, of course, when it is also **given** that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, $x$ in a neighborhood of $(s_0,t_0)$ and $y$ in a neighborhood of $(s_0,t_0)$ for the chain rule to be valid in the first place.

Comment: But, did you search the site? I suspect a similar explanation has already been given somewhere?

Comment: I just did one of these a few days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3196144/265466. You’re right that you need differentiability to apply the chain rule, but that’s generally tacitly understood in exercises like these.